# When was double-paned glass first invented and used for insulation?

Tags: thermodynamics, engineering, technology, materials-science

Double-paned glass windows have a hollow space between two panes of glass, usually just filled with air. This can make a much better insulator than normal glass, according to [Engineering Toolbox](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/heat-loss-transmission-d_748.html).

I would like to know when and where the first double-paned glass was made, and by whom? How was it constructed?

Comment: Any material constructed of two nonporous substances with a sealed vacuum or gas between them will insulate better than a single layer of the substance.  For that matter, a thick pane of class will insulate better than a thin one.  Be very cautious about your blanket statement.  In fact, certain spacings between double-pane construction will enhance heat loss due to internal vortices.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Which statement are you referring to as a blanket statement?

Comment: The part about double-pane [automatically] being better than single-pane.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Edited wording from "This makes" to "This can make".

Answer (score 5):

lmgtfy
[google cache of mimivanderhave.com](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:CRrm-gkPvE0J:directory.mimivanderhaven.com/article/a-history-of-glass.html%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

> 1945  The first double-pane, insulated window was introduced

That's without attribution;   [door and window](http://www.doorandwindow.com/windows/types/double-pane/double-pane-windows-and-ancient-history.html) claims

> From single to double pane windows… The true evolution of double pane
>   windows originated in 1913 when the Andersen Lumber Co. became the
>   first to manufacture wood window frames. In 1932 they added the sash
>   and hardware, and two years later, even the glazing. Making the entire
>   factory-squared, tight-fitting assembly was the first step in laying
>   the groundwork for what would become today's double pane windows for
>   the home. In 1952, they introduced a Welded Insulated Glass window,
>   and the double pane window was born.

An interesting note over at [ecobuildingpulse](http://www.ecobuildingpulse.com/products/efficient-window-technologies-a-history_s)  says:

> Robert Struble, communications manager at PPG Industries (formerly
>   Pittsburgh Plate Glass), says that the concept of double glazing
>   originated in the 1860s. An inventor filed a claim with the U.S.
>   Patent and Trademark Office for an insulating glass product consisting
>   of two glass panes separated by rope and bound with tar. “Of course,
>   nothing happened with [that product],” Struble says. “Nobody used it,
>   and it was not necessarily commercially viable.
>
> 1940s and '50s: Double and Triple Glazing
>
> The east- and west facings of the United Nations' headquarters in New
>   York, completed in 1953, are clad in insulated glazing. Muhammad
>   Ghouri/Flickr The east- and west facings of the United Nations'
>   headquarters in New York, completed in 1953, are clad in insulated
>   glazing. In 1945, PPG developed one of the first commercially viable
>   double-glazed IGUs in the U.S. Though they were originally used for
>   Pullman railroad cars, the units found their way into buildings the
>   following year, reducing U-factors from the 1-plus values of
>   single-glazed units to 0.47.